# How to Bring to Front a usercontrol2 in a button click in usercontrol1 c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Firstly I had been searching about my problem and can't find. I have a Form1 and a usercontrol1 and usercontrol2,  There is a button in Form1 when i click on a button the usercontrol1 will bring to front. In usercontrlol1 there is a button also when i click it the usercontrol2 will bring to front-but there is a problem usercontrol2 not appearing.

**Here is my code**;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = (this.Parent as Form1);
    f1.usercontrol2.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: check value of Visible property?

Comment: Have You made the UC visible? `Show()` snould help with that on the `UserControl`.

Comment: yes UC is set to visible. i got new error it says "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Sir is my code right?

Comment: Forcing one usercontrol to know anything about another is a Very Bad Idea.  Just raise an event, like Click by calling OnClick(), now the form can do the proper job.

Comment: @Hans Passant thank you for the response, how to do that,because i'm new in winforms c#

Comment: Researching this is the most basic way to stop being "new in winforms", it can't be skipped.  Just google "how to raise an event from a user control".

Comment: You don't need to create a variable to reference the form. Just do this.
`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    usercontrol2.BringToFront();
}`